# How to force apps to use default notification sound or vibration?

Tags: notifications, audio, vibration

Every other app has its own notification sound or vibration. Some apps have unpleasant notifications sounds or vibrations so long I think I'm receiving a call.

I like my life simple: I want all apps to use the default notification sound and vibration I selected in my system settings.

If apps all are made to use the same notification bar for visual notifications, there is very probably a way to make them all user the same sound too.

How can I do that?

Samsung Galaxy Note 2
Android 4.4.2

**Tried MacroDroid to no avail**:

[image]

**Tried xnotification also, but nada**

[image]
[image]

**I also tried Purify (which comes with King Root which is needed to install xnotification** Purify Notification captures all notifications but I can't have it produce a notification sound for itself. Even with a macro.

Comment: Tried and macro app doesn't override app native notification sound.

Comment: Any notification > vibrate. That doesn't override the sound of notifications and it randomly vibrates such as when I send a char message on line or switch apps.

Comment: **Trigger:** Notification → Notification Received → From Any Application →Text content (any) **Action** Notification Sound → Select Sound Long press on above action and select Add Constraints → Notification Volume → Volume on **Constraints:** None. Please try this

Comment: Tried but nothing.

Comment: Is the Android rooted? If yes, [XNotifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Taptigo.Xposed.XNotifications) can help you out.

Comment: Okay. Not rooted.

Comment: Please go to the main app panel > settings> system log and see if the macro name appears in the log. It should appear at the time notification arrived. If it doesn't show up, it means macro is not invoked , which calls for a double check on app settings

Comment: @firelord I rooted, installed xposed, installed xnotification and set up a notification filter but still I get the same stuff: all apps have their own notification sounds or vibrations.

Comment: Please check MacroDroid is not "greenified" and Enable MacroDroid in accessibility settings and also allow it as device administrator in security settings.

Comment: @Benjamin Did you enable the Xposed module of Xnotifications after installing it and rebooted the device?  Can you please share screenshots of the notification filter you've setup?

Comment: Yes. Enabled. Rebooted.

Comment: I have the same problem. In South East Asia we use LINE messenger, which uses a very annoying notification bell sound, which you can only change to 3 other in-app sounds. I am rooted and I even tried to modify the sound file inside the APK and reinstall the offending app. Modifying APKs will make their signature not match, which is a problem if they have server side checks. I found no solution so far.